# Orator orm, how to view (or log) the executed query?

Tags: python, skygear

Is there a way in which I can print a query generated for orator orm. When I print it, I get it as `<orator.orm.builder.Builder object at 0x7f3ee22738d0>`

I want to print the query which will be applied on database like "SELECT * from students"

I tried iterating over the object and looking for any key which will return me the query, but haven't found anything like that.

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable queries_logs in the database config file db.py 
Refer this: 
https://orator-orm.com/docs/0.9/basic_usage.html#customizing-log-messages

```
config = {
'mysql': {
    'driver': 'mysql',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'database': 'database',
    'username': 'root',
    'password': '',
    'prefix': '',
    'log_queries': True
}
```

}

If it doesn't work try the link you might need to add these

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('orator.connection.queries')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter(
    'It took %(elapsed_time)sms to execute the query %(query)s'
)

handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply use .to_sql() on the query.

Example:

```
query = db.table('accounts').select('company_name').to_sql()
print(query)
```

Result:

```
SELECT `company_name` FROM `accounts`
```